# Translating curl commands into Java/Android

Tags: java, android, curl

Can someone help me figure out how to translate the following curl commands into Java syntax for use in an Android application?

The curl commands are:

```
curl -L -c cookie1 URL

curl -L -c cookie2 -b cookie1 -d "loginId=NAME&password=PASSWORD&_eventId_submit=Submit" URL2

curl -L -c cookie3 -b cookie2 -d "_eventId_submit=Submit" URL3
```

Specifically the storing and sending of cookies.  The rest I can manage, but I'm not sure how to store the initial GET response's cookie, then send it with the subsequent POST, then send that response's cookie with the final POST.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost working...when I start an activity through a new intent, the cookies are immediately wiped.  I'll edit this answer once I have that figured out for a more complete solution, but the following does generate the desired authentication cookie.

`try {`

```
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("url1");
        client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
        if (entity1 != null){
            entity1.consumeContent();
        }
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                cookie = cookies.get(i);
            }
        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginId", username.toString()));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.toString()));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_eventId_submit", "Submit"));

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url2");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpParams params = httppost.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 45000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 45000);

        // Perform the HTTP POST request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        if (!status.contains("OK")) {
            throw new HttpException(status);
        }

        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                cookie = cookies.get(i);
            }
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nvps2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_eventId_submit", "Submit"));

        HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("url3");
        httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps2, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpParams params2 = httppost2.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params2, 45000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params2, 45000);

        // Perform the HTTP POST request
        HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(httppost2);
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                cookie = cookies.get(i);
                settings.setASCookie(cookie);
            }
        }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Edit:

I created an application class that extends Application and defined my DefaultHttpClient there, then in all my other activities, I use that client for requests.  This allows cookies to be shared across all activities in my application.